# Tampermonkey change to href reverts when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts, tampermonkey

I want to change the `href` in an element with id "apple" using Tampermonkey.

My code works, it changes the href to `www.google.com`. However, when I click the link it takes me to the old website `www.somewebsite.com`.

I don't know why this is happening. Could Tampermonkey be running my script late? It's as if the browser has cached the old href, so although the jQuery script has changed the href, but when the button is clicked it sends you to the old website?

```
<div>
<a id="apple" href="www.somewebsite.com">click to visit my website<a/>
</div>

var GMnode,GMelID;
  GMelID="nav-questions";
  GMnode=document.getElementById("apple");
  if((GMnode!==null)&&(GMnode.hasAttribute("href"))){
    GMnode.setAttribute("href","http://www.google.com/");
  }

// ==UserScript==
// @name         Apple
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  testing!
// @author       You
// @match        *://*/*
// @run-at       document-end
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The question needs either an MCVE or a link to the actual page.

We can't tell what's going on because the required example is not yet provided, but pages use a variety of techniques to mask or rewrite links.  They do this for nefarious — or for advertising (but I repeat myself) — purposes.

So, your script fails either because it's firing too soon, or because the page is rewriting the link just as you click it.

1. When you mouse over the link, does it show `www.google.com` or `www.somewebsite.com`?
2. What happens when you load the page without javascript enabled on that page?

Anyway, a technique that sometimes works is to ignore the link and make your own, like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Apple
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @run-at   document-end
// @require  https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directive is needed to restore the proper sandbox.
/* global $ */
/* eslint-disable no-multi-spaces */

var targId      = "apple";
var badLink     = $("#" + targId);
var goodLink    = badLink.clone ().attr ("id", `TM${targId}`).attr ("href", "https://www.google.com/");

badLink.hide ().after (goodLink);
```

But some pages are trickier to script around. **Provide a working example of what you are seeing.**